# What is the Sankhya view on creation?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, philosophy, sankhya

Why was the cosmic delusion created? Why does it exist?

Why was parabrahma partitioned into nature and man?

Comment: No one can answer these questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you meant the purpose of cosmic delusion, it is for higher beings to enjoy through you. For e.g., the wife is first married to 4 beings before you. Moon, agni etc. They are running your thinking, your thoughts, your involuntary actions. They sacrifice something to stay within you. Where is your soul when you sleep? You have freedom only in waking state. But, you think your soul is in control. That is local delusion - not cosmic. SImilarly, at the cosmic scale, every sentient being thinks that it is in control. That is usually not so. That is the great cosmic delusion cast by Parabrahman. Why? You have any other suggestions? Pen it & he might consider implementation :-)

Next, Nature is the 'acting' part of Parabrahman(moola prakriti).
The Still part is the other half. You are not partitioned into Nature & Man. You are part of Nature-since you move awake-eyelids flutter etc. The other part of Parabrahman is half-God. Why only half? That's your homework problem :-).

Comment: You should cite sources.

Answer (score 1):

Samkya and Advaita Vedanta seem to differ in their interpretation of the theory of causation (creation) interms of  Parinama vada and Vivarta vada

(The fundamental idea of Maya(Prakrithi) is grounded on vedic literature ( Shvetashvatara upanishad 10.4), and the terms aren't coined in Advaita or Samkya.)

Parinama Vada

The world is a transformation of the (primordial)Prakrti

All material effects are the real modifications of Prakriti. They pre-exist in prakriti and simply come out of it at the time of creation and return to it at the time of dissolution.

Vivarta Vada

The world is apparent or illusory,  from the standpoint of eternal Brahman, caused by Maya.
(The clay does not undergo any real change in becoming a pot  but it's only apparent.)

---

Chandhogya Upanishad 6.2.3

> "tad aikshata bahu syAm, prajAyeya"
> Let me be born (as many)

> The word aikṣata means ‘saw,’ ‘thought,’ or ‘decided.’ This can apply only  to consciousness principle. And only a consciousness(Chaithanyam) can  deem to say that IT will be many.

One becoming Many is  fundamental to vedic literature though its
interpretation ,either apparent or real is in  concordance with  the doctrine of Advaita Vedanta or Samkya.